# What could be the impact on SP Farm from those errors?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, object-model, dispose, spdisposechecker

I find the below error more frequently especially with the custom application pages that are developed. i saw approx 2000 of those errors in a hour span of ULS logs.

What could be the impact on SP Farm from those errors?

> 0x1588    SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    High    An SPRequest object
>   was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting
>   system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an
>   SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will
>   now be disposed.  Allocation Id:
>   {462E597D-4B57-4B66-97CD-F7BD6A1FD723}  To determine where this object
>   was allocated, set
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks
>   = true.   ef64009e-0d4d-70ed-5852-26200c72222f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are writing a `server-side object model` code in your custom application page that uses `SPSite` or `SPWeb` objects but you didn't dispose these objects and this is cause **wasting system resources**. so try to dispose these objects to release its allocated memory as the following:

---

**To dispose SPWeb object, it's preferred to use `Using` statement as the following:**

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursiteurl"))
    {

    }
```

**To dispose SPWeb object,**

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

    }
```

> **Note:** Disposing a SPWeb object will not actually remove the SPWeb object from memory  but it will call a method of the SPWeb object
>   which causes the COM object to close the connection to the SQL server
>   and to release its allocated memory.

Comment: That is how exactly we call those methods but still we are getting those errors in uls logs, we also used disposechecker to identify any memory leaks but even it didnt show anything.

Comment: Just make sure you don't dispose the ones you didn't create yourself.  :)